# data.path not found for Volume Definition, though i see its folder is created

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I want to update the volume locations on the default docker compose to something more manageable to me.

I use:

```
volumes:
  - /media/sf_dataset/data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

and I see that i see the folder data01 is created, but when the containers start, all the elastic instances fail saying they cant find the directory.

```
es03    | "stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/usr/share/elasticsearch/data)",
es03    | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]",
```

Since the folder itself is created, i presume it has permissions.

When looking at the volume location, I see it is owned by root and the group is vboxsf.  I was thinking there may need to be a special docker user I need to add to the vboxsf group but since it created the folders I think something else is afoot.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Pretty much I have dedicated drives set to it, so i mount the folders which will be the volume locations.

Backround:

Host Machine (windows) runs a VM with a shared folder to the VM.  Shared folder in this sample is just to an empty HDD.
The VM runs docker and uses the shared space: /media/sf_dataset to be the storage location for the Docker Volumes..

It seems though that docker DOES create the folder in this case: data01, but seems to have issues accessing it.  I was looking at the user permissions, etc and it seems like it works and testing it shows that I do have a means to r/w to it.

*EDIT* This issue is specific to binding to a directory that is an External HDD.... either on mac or Windows.  The directory is tagged as 755 for some reason, so I am trying to figure out how to simulate that the USER for each container is in fact the host owner of the Volume.

H:/, /media/, /Volumes/ will show that the folder itself is in a readonly state, so it cant write any files needed to be written, just read.  Since it seems i cant change the permissions of the External Drive, I need to find a way have the containers run as the current user, or some other alternative means to get write access to the HDD.